# Easeljs - Animation cycles once before moving on button click

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs, easeljs

I have an animation of a walk cycle that I am trying to move across the screen when the user presses the "a" or "d" keys.

My problem is that when either key is pressed, the animation will go through one full cycle of animation in place before it will actually move left or right.

What could be causing my animation to stay in place for one cycle before moving as it should?

Here is my current movement code:

```
var walking = false;
function walkRight() {
if (!walking)
{
    walk.gotoAndPlay("walkRight");
    walking = true;
}
walk.x += 3;
stage.addChild(walk);
}
function walkLeft(){
if (!walking)
{
    walk.gotoAndPlay("walkLeft");
    walking = true;
}
walk.x-=3;
stage.addChild(walk);
}
```

Comment: Any chance you are using the keydown event to trigger the walk function? Keydown fires once when you press it, then after a short pause (500 ms), it fires repeatedly, around 80ms in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/188pbj93/2/ -- If so, you might want to set your own repeater that turns on and off based on keydown/keyup.

Comment: I am using a keyevent:
`switch(evt.keyCode) {
        case KEYCODE_LEFT:  walkLeft(); return false;
        case KEYCODE_RIGHT: walkRight(); return false;`

Should I not be doing it like this?

Comment: Which keyevent? If you rely on keydown repeating, you will see a short delay after the first one.